# ST contains not working properly with trigger

Tags: qgis, postgresql, sql, trigger

I have table1, on which people do regular inserts, and table2, that needs to get updated based on what was inserted to table1.

table1 has

```
    id integer
    type text
    ref text
    geom polygon geometry
```

table2 has

```
    idb integer
    status integer
    ref text
    geom point geometry
```

Users can sometimes do bulk inserts into table1. My trigger function to update table2 is

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION table2update()
 RETURNS trigger
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$

BEGIN
update table2 a set status = 50, ref =  new."ref"
where new.type = 'POLE' and new."ref" is not null and st_contains(new.geom,a.geom);
RETURN new;
END;

$function$
;
```

trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER derp BEFORE INSERT ON table1 FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE table2update();
```

People do their inserts on a software called QGIS but it looks like the following

```
insert into table1(type,ref,geom)
values('POLE', 'derp','geom'),
('not pole', null, 'geom')
```

Expected behaviour, all the rows in table2 contained by the polygons in table1 will have the ref updated, as well as the status, but only where the type of inserts in table1 are 'POLE'

Actual behaviour, all the rows get updated with the status, but the type is completely ignored - in other words, the ref stays null but the status changes. When a user pastes a single row of type 'POLE', it works as intended however I do not want to encourage people not inputting all the data

How to fix the code?

Comment: Point-on-line often fails due to floating-point representation issues -- don't use it. Instead use `ST_DWithin` with a very small tolerance.

Comment: @Vince no points on line. Changed st contains to dwithin and still nothing. The problem is the overlapping polygons